# Input autofill background color with border radius

Tags: css

I have an input with a border radius of `10px` and I change it's autofill background color like this

```
  input:-webkit-autofill,
  input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
  input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
  input:-webkit-autofill:active,
  input:-internal-autofill-selected,
  input:-internal-autofill-previewed {
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #202327 inset;
  }
```

The problem is the corners remain the original white color after I select an autofill option.

My code is something like this

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

input {
  height: 3rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  background-color: #202327;
  outline: none;
}

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-internal-autofill-selected,
input:-internal-autofill-previewed {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #202327 inset;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: white !important;
  caret-color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" />
```

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML and any other applicable CSS?

Comment: seems to be no issue with white corners. Please check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/cn68k5zy/3/). If it happens in a certain browser please include that in the question.

Comment: @Kameron the corners are only present after selecting an autofill option. Also forgot to mention, it's happening in Chormium

Answer (score 0):

this works perfectly

```
.field {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 30px #2E2E2E !important;
  background-clip: content-box !important;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).